# Get and then remove random object from Knockout ObservableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to grab a random object from an observable array and then remove the object from the array so that it isn't grabbed again. However, it seems like all of the objects are being removed too quickly and incorrectly so I run out of objects.

https://jsfiddle.net/vwfp9L7s/

HTML:

```
<ul id="personList">
  <li data-bind="with: getPerson() ">
    <p data-bind="text: $data.name"></p>
  </li>
  <li data-bind="with: getPerson() ">
    <p data-bind="text: $data.name"></p>
  </li>
  <li data-bind="with: getPerson() ">
    <p data-bind="text: $data.name"></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function PersonVM() {
  this.people = ko.observableArray([{
      name: "bob",
      age: 22
    },
    {
      name: "bill",
      age: 23
    },
    {
      name: "sue",
      age: 24
    },
  ])
  this.getPerson = function() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.people().length);
    var randomPerson = this.people()[random];
    this.people.remove(randomPerson);
    console.log(this.people().length);
    return randomPerson;
  }
}
ko.applyBindings(PersonVM, document.getElementById("personList"));
```

This is only ouputting 2 person li's and leaving the third blank. If you look at the console log, the arrays length goes 2, 0, 0.

Why is .remove removing all of my objects and not the used one?

Comment: Actually, if you look more carefully, your function is being called more times than you expect.

Comment: I think your problem is that when it grabs the second value you are forcing a re-evaluation of the first because the bindings have been updated

Comment: Your best solution here might be to use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to shuffle your array, and then just bind your now shuffled array with a `foreach` binding.

Answer (score 0):

As @Matt said you're triggering `getPerson` to re-evalute. Here's why:

You have a vm that has an observableArray and you bind that to your view. There are 3 bindings to the `getPerson` in your view. As the view is rendered it calls the `getPerson` function, but on each call it mutates the `people` observableArray. That mutation triggers the view to re-render because there is a change in the vm.

You're using a function that returns a random person from a list so there is no reason for the people array to be observable. You only need observable properties when you want to drive a view update on change. In this case its not only unnecessary but its also causing an unintended side-effect.

**Solution 1:**

A simple fix would be for the `people` property to be a plain array:

```js
function PersonVM() {
  this.people = [{
      name: "bob",
      age: 22
    },
    {
      name: "bill",
      age: 23
    },
    {
      name: "sue",
      age: 24
    },
  ]
  this.getPerson = function() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.people.length);
    var randomPerson = this.people[random];
    this.people.splice(random, 1);
    console.log(this.people.length);
    return randomPerson;
  }
}
```

You'll need to use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) since JS Arrays don't have a remove method.

**Solution 2:**

As an alternative you could keep the observableArray and fill it in random order from a plain JS array. Then you can have a simpler view binding